# How to create List View in java that are checkable

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a list with checkboxes in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766/how-do-i-make-a-list-with-checkboxes-in-java-swing)

I want to display some items in a list which are checkable . User can Select/Deselect an item in the list . Or in otherwards

and if the item in the list is double clicked then there will be some command

can anyone help me with this

Comment: thx sorry i did not look before for the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JTable with two columns:

- an editable boolean one for the checkbox
- a non-editable one for the text

Read the [Swing tutorial about tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).