# How to add checkboxes in list in java

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jscrollpane, jlist

Hey everyone I am trying to add checkboxes into JList but for some reasons it's giving me `IllegalArgumentException`. If anyone know how to add checkbox in JList please tell me. Thank you in advance

```
    JCheckBox []data={
    new JCheckBox("C"),
    new JCheckBox("C++"),
    new JCheckBox("Java"),
    new JCheckBox("C sharp")};
    JList l=new JList(data);
    JScrollPane sp=new  JScrollPane(l,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Comment: Where do you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the full exception message:

```
IllegalArgumentException: invalid verticalScrollBarPolicy
```

caused when `JScrollPane` is instantiated. The `JScrollPane` policies are the wrong way around:

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(l,
        ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int%29) for `JScrollPane`. The second parameter should be the Veritical scrollbar policy, not the Horizontal:

```
public JScrollPane(Component view, int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy)
```

Answer (score 0):

The illegalArgumentExceptions ocurs because you switch the horizontal scrollbar policy with the vertical scrollbar policy.

But with this code you will not get a list of checkbox, only the text representation of the objets.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766/how-do-i-make-a-list-with-checkboxes-in-java-swing)

Comment: ya it solve the problem but not showing any checkbox it showing objects in JList