# Dynamic Checkbox in JFrame/Swing

Tags: java, database, swing, checkbox, jframe

I want to populate List of tables as a dynamic checkbox using Jframe/Swing in netbeans. The count of table is not known as i am giving USER to select DB as well. Please help, below is code which is for populating list of tables as combo box

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)          
{                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String dbValue=(String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
    String Connection = jTextField1.getText();
    String User = jTextField2.getText();
    char[] pwd = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //bt2.setEnabled(false);
    Object ob=evt.getSource();
     if (ob == jButton2)
     {

           /* String Connection = tf1.getText();
            String User = tf2.getText();
            char[] pwd = p1.getPassword();*/
            System.out.println("**************");
            try
               {
                String passwrd=String.valueOf(pwd);
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Connection,User,passwrd);
                    Statement st=con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs2= st.executeQuery("SELECT Count(*) FROM DBA_TABLES where owner='"+dbValue+"'");
                    if(rs2.next()){
                         count=rs2.getInt(1);

                    }
                    generateCheckboxesDynamically(count);
                    System.out.println("Count="+count);
                    ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select table_name from dba_tables where owner='"+dbValue+"'");

                    while(rs1.next())
                    {
                           for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){ 
                           JCheckBox jCheckBoxMenu=new JCheckBox("check"+i);

                           jCheckBoxMenu.setText(rs1.getString(1));
                           add(jCheckBoxMenu);
                           checks.add(jCheckBoxMenu); 
                           jCheckBoxMenu.setVisible(true);
                           }
                           pack();
                            //JCheckBox ma=new JCheckBox; 
                        String name = rs1.getString(1);
                        if (name.equals("")) {
                                        jComboBox1.removeAll();
                        jComboBox1.addItem("");
                        jComboBox1.setVisible(false);
                        } 
                        else {
                        jComboBox1.addItem(rs1.getString(1));

                        System.out.println(rs1.getString(1));
                        jComboBox1.setVisible(true);
                        }
                            jTextField1.setEnabled(false);
                            jTextField2.setEnabled(false);
                            //tf3.setEnabled(false);
                          jButton1.setEnabled(false); 
                     }
                    //String dbValue=(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
                    System.out.println("Selected DB=="+dbValue);
                    //bt2.setEnabled(true);
                    //bt1.removeActionListener(this);
               } 
                    catch (Exception ex) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
               }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766/how-do-i-make-a-list-with-checkboxes-in-java-swing?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please post [MCVE]